# Can I group rows in a Javafx TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, treeview, tableview

I'd like to make a javafx TableView with rows that may (or may not) have "related" rows. Basically, I think it might be a tableview of tableviews, but (a) I'm not sure that would work and (b) my gut tells me there's an easier way.

Imagine a bill or materials like

```
item    material    quantity    name
1       wood        1           base
2       wood        4           drawer
        wood        4           drawer sides
        wood        1           drawer base
        hardware    1           pull
        hardware    8           nails
3       aluminum    4           leg
        plastic     1           foot
        hardware    1           screws
```

Right now, it's sorted by name (base, drawer, leg). If I sort it by material, I want the items to be 3, 1, 2 (or 3, 2, 1): aluminum, wood, wood. I need the "subitems" to remain with the numbered items.

Can I make "complex rows"? (And I don't even know what I'd call it!)
Or do I need a custom sort that will keep groups together?

Comment: Looking for [`TreeTableView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to check out [`TreeTableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html). With it, you may be able to sort by whatever criteria you like, while at the same time having the records grouped by any other criteria (for example by `name`)

This component gets its data from a tree structure model built on the [`TreeItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) class.

With it a root `TreeItem` can be built for the root object of your bill of materials having as children a `TreeItem` for each group you want (name of the material?). Then, each of these *grouping* `TreeItem` objects should contain as children the corresponding `TreeItem` children for each of the actual `material` in the bill of materials being displayed.

There are multiple good tutorials out there that cover in detail the technical aspects of this:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm
- https://o7planning.org/en/11149/javafx-treetableview-tutorial
- https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-treetableview-example/

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I looked through the javafx controls, I saw TreeTableView and thought it was a TreeView, ie, no columns. This is much easier than my options and I thank you, Marco.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses a TreeTableView to represent the data rather than a TableView.

It uses a demonstration data model with hard-coded data.

The complicated nested lambda expressions could be replaced by procedural code mapping your actual model data to the TreeItem data structure which backs the TreeTableView.

[image: screenshot]

```
import java.util.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TreeTableViewSample extends Application {

    private final List<String> employeesNames = Arrays.asList(
            "Ethan Williams",
            "Emma Jones",
            "Michael Brown"
    );

    private final Random random = new Random(42);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<DutyAssignment> assignments =
                determineAssignments(employeesNames);

        TreeItem<DutyAssignment> assignmentTree = createAssignmentTree(assignments);
        TreeTableView<DutyAssignment> dutyAssignmentView = createAssigmentTreeTableView(assignmentTree);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(dutyAssignmentView));
        stage.show();
    }

    private TreeTableView<DutyAssignment> createAssigmentTreeTableView(TreeItem<DutyAssignment> root) {
        TreeTableColumn<DutyAssignment, String> employeeColumn =
                new TreeTableColumn<>("Employee");
        employeeColumn.setPrefWidth(120);
        employeeColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                param -> param.getValue().getValue().nameProperty()
        );

        TreeTableColumn<DutyAssignment, Workday> dayColumn =
                new TreeTableColumn<>("Day");
        dayColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        dayColumn.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                param.getValue().getValue().dayProperty()
        );

        TreeTableColumn<DutyAssignment, Duty> dutyColumn =
                new TreeTableColumn<>("Duty");
        dutyColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
        dutyColumn.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                param.getValue().getValue().dutyProperty()
        );

        TreeTableView<DutyAssignment> dutyAssignmentView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
        dutyAssignmentView.getColumns().setAll(employeeColumn, dayColumn, dutyColumn);
        dutyAssignmentView.setShowRoot(false);
        dutyAssignmentView.setPrefSize(380, 500);
        
        return dutyAssignmentView;
    }

    private TreeItem<DutyAssignment> createAssignmentTree(ObservableList<DutyAssignment> assignments) {
        TreeItem<DutyAssignment> root = new TreeItem<>(
                new DutyAssignment("All Assignments", null, null)
        );
        root.setExpanded(true);
        employeesNames.stream()
                .sorted()
                .forEach(employeeName -> {
                    TreeItem<DutyAssignment> employeeTitleItem = new TreeItem<>(
                            new DutyAssignment(employeeName, null, null)
                    );
                    root.getChildren().add(employeeTitleItem);
                    employeeTitleItem.setExpanded(true);

                    assignments.stream()
                            .sorted()
                            .filter(assignment -> employeeName.equals(assignment.getName()))
                            .forEach(dutyAssignment -> {
                                TreeItem<DutyAssignment> assignmentLineItem = new TreeItem<>(
                                        new DutyAssignment(null, dutyAssignment.getDay(), dutyAssignment.getDuty())
                                );
                                employeeTitleItem.getChildren().add(assignmentLineItem);
                            });
                });
        
        return root;
    }

    private ObservableList<DutyAssignment> determineAssignments(List<String> employeesNames) {
        ObservableList<DutyAssignment> assignments = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (String employeeName : employeesNames) {
            for (Workday day : Workday.values()) {
                assignments.add(
                        new DutyAssignment(
                                employeeName,
                                day,
                                selectRandomDuty()
                        )
                );
            }
        }

        return assignments;
    }

    private Duty selectRandomDuty() {
        return
                Duty.values()[
                        random.nextInt(
                                Duty.values().length
                        )
                ];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TreeTableViewSample.class, args);
    }

    public class DutyAssignment implements Comparable<DutyAssignment> {
        final private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        final private SimpleObjectProperty<Workday> day = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        final private SimpleObjectProperty<Duty> duty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        final private Comparator<DutyAssignment> nameDayDutyComparator =
                Comparator.comparing(DutyAssignment::getName)
                        .thenComparing(DutyAssignment::getDay)
                        .thenComparing(DutyAssignment::getDuty);

        public DutyAssignment(String name, Workday day, Duty duty) {
            setName(name);
            setDay(day);
            setDuty(duty);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public Workday getDay() {
            return day.get();
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Workday> dayProperty() {
            return day;
        }

        public void setDay(Workday day) {
            this.day.set(day);
        }

        public Duty getDuty() {
            return duty.get();
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Duty> dutyProperty() {
            return duty;
        }

        public void setDuty(Duty duty) {
            this.duty.set(duty);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(DutyAssignment o) {
            return nameDayDutyComparator.compare(this, o);
        }
    }

    public enum Duty {
        WRITING, EDITING, COLORING, COMPOSITING
    }

    public enum Workday {
        MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY
    }
}
```